# Issue using @RetryableTopic in kafka

Tags: java, spring-kafka

we were using the @RetryableTopic in a springboot application to do a nonblocking retry having a fixed delay(like 5 hrs), but when the application starts was getting error like
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 (retry topic)TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED. appreciate anyone's help

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring or retryable topics - it simply means you do not have authorization to consume from that topic. You need to consult your system admins.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. These retryable topics i thought will be automatically created. So should we create them manually and ask the system admins to give access to the account to access the retry topic as well (in addition to the main topic)? The consumption from the main topic worked fine before i added this @RetryableTopic to implement retries.

Comment: They are created, if permissions allow, and you don't disable it; but your user's permissions don't allow to read from it.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell for the quick response. In our case I believe we cannot create topics on the fly from our application. So I will have to create a retry topic(just like how i created the main topic) and give access to for my account to write to it and then post the message from the main topic to this topic, which has to be retried n a specific time frame, right?

Comment: Set `autoCreateTopics` to `false` on the annotation; you have to post to the main topic, the framework will set up a header in the record written to the retry topic with the timestamp of the retry time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We were posting to retryabletopic based on when a specific exception is thrown, but now seems like its trying to move to a deadletter queue (even though in @RetryableTopic annotation DltStrategy.NO_DLT is set)and not getting posted to the retry topic, you have any thoughts why it might be happening